# Delphi: Getting the UnitName of the caller function

Tags: delphi

```
unit MyFirstUnit;
  uses MyTranslateUnit;
  ...
  sText := Dictionary('text to translate', UnitName);
  ...
end.
```

```
unit AnotherUnit;
  uses MyTranslateUnit;
  ...
  sText := Dictionary('new text to translate', UnitName);
  ...
end.
```

```
unit MyTranslateUnit;
  function Dictionary(sTextToTranslate: string; sUnitName: string)
  begin
    // Here I need the UnitName of the caller
    Result := ...
  end;
end.
```

There are quite many places in my program where I call **Dictionary(...)**. How can I avoid passing the UnitName as second parameter?
Is it possible to get the UnitName of the caller within MyTranslateUnit without having a second parameter?

I want to have a function like

> function Dictionary(sTextToTranslate: string)

Comment: The short answer is that Delphi does not natively support what you are asking for. However, there are 3rd party solutions that do (particular 3rd party stack tracers). It usually involves generating a `.map` or `.tds` file for your project and deploy it with your app (if not linked statically), and then having the function retrieve its own `ReturnAddress` and match it to a particular entry in the `.map`/`.tds` file to figure out what the caller's name is and which unit implements it.

Comment: Presumably you want this for debugging purposes, otherwise you have an objectively terrible design (no matter what excuses you may come up with). So, getting back to debugging ... you're tackling this in an awkward, narrow and roundabout way. You'd be better off looking into the concept of _stack tracing_. And there are many debugging tools that facilitate this: * Exceptional Magic; * Mad Except; * Jcl Debug. To name a few.

Answer (score 6):

As long as the call happens inside a method of a class, you can simply write `UnitName`. Every Delphi `TObject` provides the `class function UnitName: string;` which gives the name of unit the class is declared in.

This won't give you the possibility to omit the second parameter, but it simplifies the maintenance when units are renamed or code is copied or moved between units.

**Edit:** There is a real dirty hack to make this work without the second parameter and it also works only within a method of a class. I suggest to make use of this only as a last resort! The benefit of removing one parameter can easily backfire in the future.

Declare a *class helper* for TObject like this:

```
type
  TRealDirtyDontDoItObjectHelper = class helper for TObject
  public
    class function Dictionary(const sTextToTranslate: string): string;
  end;

implementation

class function TRealDirtyDontDoItObjectHelper.Dictionary(const sTextToTranslate: string): string;
begin
  { whatever implementation should go here }
  Result := UnitName + ': ' + sTextToTranslate;
end;
```

Now you can call something like

```
Caption := Dictionary('title');
```

inside any method where `UnitName` gives the unit where the class the method belongs is declared in. Note that this means the class of the current instance and not necessarily some inherited class where the method is declared.

I should also mention, that this *class helper for TObject* doesn't interfere with class helpers for any other class, even if these obviously inherit from `TObject`.

Comment: Is there something like "parent.UnitName" or do I have to write this second parameter every time I call Dictionary()?

Comment: This solution reports the implementation `UnitName` of the class method that is being called, not the `UnitName` of whatever code is calling the method, which can easily be in another unit. So I'm downvoting this as it doesn't address the actual question that was asked: "*Is it possible to get the UnitName **of the caller**...*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it reports the name of the unit where the call to Dictionary is done, not the unit where the class method Dictionary is declared. Tested under Delphi 10.2.2. I would be interested in a proof of your objection.

Comment: @UweRaabe: I tried the code you have presented. The `UnitName` reported by the helper is the unit of the object that the helper is called on. It is the unit of the **caller** ONLY when the caller is a class method that calls the helper via the caller's own `Self` pointer. Maybe that is how you intended it. But call the helper on some other object, and you get different results. And you can't call the helper from a non-class procedure unless you call it via a class type, but then you get that class's unit. not the caller's unit. So this is still not a very flexible solution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, indeed, and it is not only what I intended but also exactly what I wrote. The example of the call doesn't show a call to _someobject.Dictionary_ on purpose.
Anyway, I accept that you don't like this solution - me neither.

Comment: is there any way to do this in some plain function/procedure (not method) of a unit without delcaring some dummy class just to call UnitName on it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible but only with additional code in each unit

```
type
  TDummy = class(TObject)
  end;

function Dictionary(sTextToTranslate: string): string;
begin
  Result := MyTranslateUnit.Dictionary(sTextToTranslate, TDummy.UnitName);
end;
```